# Bookdown: How can I change the size of the chapter titles?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am using bookdown to generate slides for a workshop. I use the 'big' letter option in the menu for display as slides. However then the chapter title font size is too large. Where/how can I modify that one?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Your question is not very clear.  if you post the code which you all ready have it will make it easier to develop a solution for you.

Comment: upload minimal working code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can control this with .css as [yihui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559676/yihui) suggests

in the top level of your bookdown project there is a file called style.css
open it and paste in:

```
    .book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal h1{font-size:1em}
```

this will increase the size of your top level header font when you build the book. you can change the value of 'em' or you can use other ways of specifiying font size such as '%' or 'pt'. you can also change h1 to h2, h3 etc to change 2nd, 3rd level headers and so on.

i recommend reading a little about .css

style the web like a badass

Comment: Thanks! I did it for h2, h3 as well so it works for sub chapters as well. Do you maybe also have an idea on changing the space between the chapter titles and the top/menu bar? For slides it would be ideal to minimize that space.

Comment: try the .css attributes margin-top e.g. 

`.book .book-body .page-wrapper .page-inner section.normal h1{
font-size: 1em;
margin-top: 3em
}`