# Improve visibility/ Increase font size of one column in table: pdf output produced with kableextra

Tags: r, fonts, latex, r-markdown, kable

I'm producing a pdf document with rmarkdown.

I produce a table with the following code:

YAML:

```
---
title: "Queries"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: false
    latex_engine: xelatex
mainfont: Arial
---
```

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
```

```
{r query}
df <- data.frame(a =  rep("text", 3),
                 b = c("\\uparrow", " \\leftrightarrow", "\\downarrow"),
                 c = rep(" lots more text ...", ))

df%>%
  kbl(longtable = FALSE, escape = F, booktabs =  T, align = "c")%>%
  column_spec(1, width =  "8em")%>%
  column_spec(3, width = "9em")%>%
  column_spec(2, bold = TRUE, color = "red")%>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 8)
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

I'd really like to make the 2nd column `b` more visible, ideally by **increasing font size of that column only**, thus increasing the size of the arrows. Is this possible or are there alternative ways to produce the same effect?

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67265919/13249862) answer your question?

Comment: no that answer is to increase size of caption. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz MWE with YAML inserted. Thanks

Comment: If you're open to using a different package, my `huxtable` does this like `set_font_size(everywhere, "b", 14)` where `"b"` is the column name. I'm not certain how font size plays with `\leftarrow` and friends; could be unicode and xetex would help here.

Comment: @dash2 thanks. Do you know if `huxtable` is able to produced tables that span multiple pages, like `longtable`?

Comment: You can use `longtable`, via `huxtable::table_environment`. It's not completely tested with it, though. You can also split tables easily using `huxtable::split_across`. Headers will be preserved on both sides of the split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your desired font size to your arrows:

````
---
title: "Queries"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{xcolor}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    toc: false
    latex_engine: lualatex
    keep_tex: true
mainfont: Arial
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(stringr)
library(readxl)
```


```{r query}
df <- data.frame(a =  rep("text", 3),
                 b = c("\\LARGE\\uparrow", " \\LARGE\\leftrightarrow", "\\LARGE\\downarrow"),
                 c = rep(" lots more text ...", ))

df%>%
  kbl(longtable = FALSE, escape = F, booktabs =  T, align = "c")%>%
  column_spec(1, width =  "8em")%>%
  column_spec(3, width = "9em")%>%
  column_spec(2, bold = TRUE, color = "red")%>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 8)
```
````

[image]