# Convert kable table in R to Latex source code

Tags: r, latex, kableextra, overleaf

I made a relatively simple table in R using kable, which outputs the actual table.  I would like to get the Latex source code so that I can add it to an overleaf document (as required for journal submission).

I have tried specifying format= 'latex' as suggested in other posts, but nothing appears in the console when I run this line of code.

```
    Table 3<-kbl(Table3Data) %>%
      row_spec(0, bold = T) %>%
      kable_classic(html_font ="times")%>%
      pack_rows("Decision Tree",1, 2) %>%
      pack_rows("Boosted Tree ",3, 4)%>%
      add_header_above(c(" "=1, "Observation level performance"=6))

    print(Table3)

    kable(Table3, format = "latex")
```

Comment: Maybe try an rmarkdown document like https://stackoverflow.com/a/69964145/2777074 By using the `keep_tex: true` option, you will find the intermediate tex file in your working directory

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Try putting the `format=` in the `kbl()` like `kbl(Table3Data, format="latex")`

Comment: MrFlick is right, try `kbl(mtcars, format = "latex") |> 
  add_header_above(c("blah" = 12))`